# Android:set ImageView dynamically?

Tags: android, layout, dynamic, imageview, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to download an image, and create an ImageView dynamically and add it to my layout, but it won't display the image. Here is my code:

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
image.setLayoutParams(vp);
image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
image.setMaxHeight(50);
image.setMaxWidth(50);
image.setImageDrawable(avatar);
theLayout.addView(image);
```

maybe I need to refresh the layout after I add the ImageView? How do you "refresh"?

Comment: Please try the dynamically image creation and adding with a non downloaded image (try to use a drawable from your drawable folder). If that works, we know the issue is with the downloading, otherwise its really a layout issue

Comment: if its an image he downloaded, wouldn't he want to use `setImageURI()` or `setImageBitmap()`?  Isn't setImageDrawable for items in the drawable folders only?

Comment: Are you adding multiple images? What is avatar?

Comment: @WarrenFaith there is not problem with downloading.

Comment: @willytate I used Drawable.createFromStream

Comment: Check out this TUT: http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/imageview-with-loading-spinner-t49439.html :-)

Comment: @Harshad I tried, it didn't help. @Mike dg no I just download one image. avatar is a Drawable

Comment: @Alex1987 ahh, gotcha! nevermind then!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add images dynamically to an ImageView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121851/how-to-add-images-dynamically-to-an-imageview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following code, and you will not need to refresh. Put your image url into the `inputurl` variable.

```
InputStream is = null;
String inputurl = " Enter url of ur image ";
try {
        URL url = new URL(inputurl);
        Object content = url.getContent();
        is = (InputStream) content;
        avatar = Drawable.createFromStream(is,"src");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}

ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
image.setLayoutParams(vp);
image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
image.setMaxHeight(50);
image.setMaxWidth(50);
image.setImageDrawable(avatar);
theLayout.addView(image);
```

Comment: Brilliant fellows please comment the reason for downvote otherwise it will be considered as revenge.

Answer (score 1):

I think u have to deifne the parameters for the vp

if u will define parameters it will display the image like-

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams Params=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        Params.setMargins(0,0,0,0);

        Params=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use another thread to download the image, and after download finishes you can update the drawable by using a handler. You can see how to make another thread at the documentation. It does not seems easy but it would be better to learn how to do it, if you want to build more responsive android apps.

(title) Example ProgressDialog with a second thread
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html